# How can I find which version of a2dp is used by my Bluetooth headset device?

Tags: bluetooth, hci

I know that one way to find this out is to have a look at the device specification. Most device specifications are reporting just that A2DP is supported. Is there another way to find which version of A2DP is used from a headset device?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using linux with either built in bluetooth or with a bluetooth dongle. Then you can use the bluez tool sdptool from the command line to get this information.

A protocol sniffer is not necessary as all a protocol sniffer does is decode the packets over the air (which is exactly what sdptool does already), and it is more difficult as you will need to find out the link key as well which, depending on the devices you are using, can be quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are only 2 versions of A2DP - 1.0 and 1.2
The differences are only minor optimizations / adaptations. So from a user's point of view it really does not matter.
Both versions are compatible and will talk to each other.

Since the differences are minor technical documentation changes in the spec it is not marketed as different versions to the end user. (Its just A2DP)
To really know the versions you will have to hook up with a Protocol sniffer and look at the SDP (Service Discovery) Query which typically happens after pairing / initial connection.